# Homotopy equivalence between $\{x\in \overline{B}^n : x_n > 0 \} $ and $\{ x \in \overline{B}^n : x_n = 0 \}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $n \in \Bbb N$ and $X$ be the ”semicircle” $\{x\in \overline{B}^n : x_n > 0 \}$. Let $A = \{ x \in \overline{B}^n : x_n = 0 \}$. Show that the inclusion $j : A \hookrightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence. Hint: Use the projection $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-1} \times \{0\}$.

I’ve tried so simplify the problem down a bit using $n = 2$. For this case I have that $X$ is the ”semidisc” and I guess that $A = (1,0) \cap (-1,0)$?

So if I define $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^ \times \{0\} $, then I would need to show that $j \circ f \simeq id_X$ and I guess that $f \circ j \simeq id_A$? The latter should be defined since $A \subset \Bbb R^ \times \{0\} $ right?

Since $j$ is the inclusion $j \circ f$ only depends on how I construct $f$, but I’m not sure how I should go about this?

Comment: How do you get that $A = (-1,0) \cap (0,1)$? It should be $[-1, 1]$

Comment: $A \cap X = \emptyset$, thus $j : A \hookrightarrow X$  does not exist. And you should tell us what $\bar B^n$ is.

Comment: As Paul Frost says, $A$ is not a subset of $X$, therefore the question does not make sense.  Perhaps you want to consider $X = \{x\in \overline{B}^n : x_n \ge 0 \}$. If so, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$, $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0)$, be the projection and $j : A \hookrightarrow X$ the inclusion map. We see that
$$
(f \circ j)(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0) = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0),
$$
so $f \circ j = \text{id}_A$, so in particular $f \circ j \simeq \text{id}_A$. Next, we see that
$$
(j \circ f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = j(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0) = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0). 
$$
Define a map $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$ by $H((x_1,\ldots,x_n),t) := (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},tx_n)$. $H$ is continuous as the product of continuous maps. Moreover, we have
\begin{align}
H((x_1,\ldots,x_n),0) &= (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0) = (j\circ f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\\
H((x_1,\ldots,x_n),1) &= (x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \text{id}_X(x_1,\ldots,x_n),
\end{align}
so $H$ defines a homotopy. Hence, $j \circ f \simeq \text{id}_X$. Hope this helps!

Comment: $A$ is not a subset of $X$. Thus there is no inclusion $j : A \to X$.

Comment: @KritikerderElche I just assumed OP meant $\{ x \in \overline{B}^n \mid x_n \geq 0 \}$, because to me that was the only thing that made sense. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: I agree, see my comment to the question.